# Eclipse CDT, Why does Eclipse prepends 'lib' to the name of a shared library?

Tags: c++, eclipse, makefile

I am using Eclipse Eclipse 2022-09 with CDT 10.7.1202208222120 on Fedora 37.

I am working on a simple C++ testapplication (libTest.cpp) which should use code from 2 shared librarys (libBasexCpp and libBasexSocket).
All 3 sources compile without errors and building libTest also completes without error. In the Properties -> Settings -> Build Artifact dialog for libBasexCpp and libBasexSocket, I have chosen not to use a Output Prefix (prefix is ""). In the debug directorys, libBasexCpp.so and libBasexSocket.so are created.
When I try to run the testapplication as a local C/C++ application, I first have to choose which local application should be run , liblibTest or libTest.
Executing either one of the 2 results in a message, saying that ***liblib***BasexCpp can not be found.

I have added Library Paths (DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH = ${workspace_loc:/libBasexCpp/Debug};${workspace_loc:/libBasexSocket/Debug} as Environmentvariable to the run configuration.

How can I configure Eclipse in such way that it loads the shared library's?

Comment: When asking questions please re-read them after posting (or use the preview feature before posting) for formatting issues that make your question hard to read, and resolve them by using the "Edit" link.

Comment: You say you're using Fedora, which is a GNU/Linux distribution.  `DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH` is a variable that is specifically available on MacOS.  It has no effect or use on GNU/Linux (or any other POSIX-based system); POSIX systems use `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`.  Also, you appear to be separating your directories in the variable with semicolons (`;`): that's a Windows convention.  All POSIX-based systems use colons (`:`) as path separators.

Comment: DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH has been removed.

Comment: I saw that the liblibTest run configuration was created in one of the earlier attempts to build libTest. After deleting the liblibTest run configuration and rebuilding the project, I still have the same error. Does it help if I upload the makefile?

Comment: You never addressed my first comment above, to edit your question so that it was readable, so I didn't reply while waiting for that.  Glad you figured out your problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically, to configure the shared librarys and the test application, I followed the instructions as I found on [Shared libraries with Eclipse CDT and cygwin on Windows](https://eclipsesource.com/blogs/2010/03/03/shared-libraries-with-eclipse-cdt-and-cygwin-on-windows/).
What was missing therein was the instruction to add in the Run configuration the variable LD_LIBRARY_PATH containing the paths to both libraries.
After adding this variable, the test application worked.